# How to read and load data from local file when page loads

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to load local file data & populate that data while page loads.

I tried to use this jquery function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
       $("div.footerText").load("footerText.txt");
   });
</script>
```

But this results in following error

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:////footerText.txt' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, edge, https, chrome-untrusted.*

Basically I am trying to write a simple HTML page which loads data into different div by reading files that are in the same code base.
here is rough structure of html

```
<head>...</head>
<body>
  <div id="headerText">
  <div id="mainText">
  <div id="footerText">
  <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("div#headerText").load("headerText.txt");
        $("div#mainText").load("mainText.txt");
        $("div#footerText").load("footerText.txt");
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This is generally a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-error-for-request-ma) in the security sense, hence your CORS error. Moreover, are you hoping to read this server-side or client-side? Because it'll fail unless clients have the requisite files long before any CORS issues arise. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493323/cross-origin-request-for-local-file).

Comment: Will work fine if you run a localhost server and open the main page on `http://localhost`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not do that.. and that seems kinda impossible.
Have a look at this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493323/cross-origin-request-for-local-file) for more details