# Firefox generates cross-origin error even when audio file is in same folder

Tags: audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm new to using audio with html and I'm encountering a cross-origin error. I'm trying to follow the Mozilla developer website's introduction to using audio, with the following code:

```
<audio src="track.mp3"></audio>
<button onclick="playTrack()">Play</button>

<script>
function playTrack(){
    const audioElement = document.querySelector("audio");  
    const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    const audioContext = new AudioContext();
    //audioElement.play()
    const track = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
    track.connect(audioContext.destination);
    }
</script>
```

But I'm getting the following error message from Firefox:

```
The HTMLMediaElement passed to createMediaElementSource has a cross-origin resource, the node will output silence.
```

I tried adding `<audio crossorigin="anonymous" ...>` but now there is an error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/track.mp3. (Reason: CORS request not http).
```

The mp3 file is in the same folder as the html file and the audio is started with a button click --  shouldn't this avoid cross-origin problems?

When I uncomment the `audioElement.play()` line and comment the following two lines, it plays normally.

Comment: Does the address bar for this page start with `file://`, `http://` or `https://`?

Comment: @fdcpp It's ``file://...`` I'm testing out how to play sounds and waveforms on browsers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493323/cross-origin-request-for-local-file

Comment: You have to serve the file over a http server. You should be able to do  that via your IDE, or python or a browser plug-in